# Why the ArrayList always returns the last object?

Tags: java

i'm working with ArrayList to get data from another object, the problem is that i always the last element of the array as an out put

This is my function:

```
public ArrayList<CheckResults> extractCheckingResults() {

        CheckResults resultRow = new CheckResults();
        ArrayList<CheckResults> results = new ArrayList<CheckResults>();

        //Getting the size of the table
        int rowNum = iplist.length;


        // Fetching the data from the table
        for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {          

            resultRow.setId(id.getText());
            resultRow.setIp(ip.getText());
            resultRow.setDomain(domain.getText());

            results.add(resultRow);
        }

        results.forEach(row -> {
            System.out.print("\n");
            System.out.print("ID: " + row.getId().toString() + "\n");
            System.out.print("IP: " + row.getIp().toString() + "\n");
            System.out.print("Domain: " + row.getDomain().toString() + "\n");
            System.out.print("----------------------------------------------\n");
        });

        return results;
    }
```

The `resultRow` Object is for getting data and set it to `results`'s next empty index

This is the output i get when i run this function:

```
ID: 9
IP: 1.2.3.4 (same ip)
Domain: www.same-domain.com
----------------------------------------------

ID: 9
IP: 1.2.3.4 (same ip)
Domain: www.same-domain.com
----------------------------------------------

ID: 9
IP: 1.2.3.4 (same ip)
Domain: www.same-domain.com
----------------------------------------------

ID: 9
IP: 1.2.3.4 (same ip)
Domain: www.same-domain.com
----------------------------------------------

ID: 9
IP: 1.2.3.4 (same ip)
Domain: www.same-domain.com
----------------------------------------------

ID: 9
IP: 1.2.3.4 (same ip)
Domain: www.same-domain.com
----------------------------------------------

ID: 9
IP: 1.2.3.4 (same ip)
Domain: www.same-domain.com
----------------------------------------------
```

I don't get where the problem is

Comment: Because you have only a single resultRow that you keep overwriting. You need to create a *new* one for each row, e.g., move the declaration into the loop.

Comment: `CheckResults resultRow = new CheckResults();` this one only has one result, do `foreach` loop on `resultRow`.

Answer (score 2):

`CheckResults resultRow = new CheckResults();` creates a single instance of `CheckResults`. You then modify that instance and add it multiple times to the same `List`. You need to create new instances to add to your `List` **in** your loop. Like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {          
    CheckResults resultRow = new CheckResults();
    resultRow.setId(id.getText());
    resultRow.setIp(ip.getText());
    resultRow.setDomain(domain.getText());
    results.add(resultRow);
}
```

Comment: That was really helpful! Thank you!!